# CASE statement for checking a field value

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, case

Hopefully you guy's can help.

I am writing a query from a table which has variable data specifically a `completed` column which can have a value of `1` or `3` the table also has two qty_ fields `QTYORDERED` and `QTYSHIPPED`

If the value is `3` in `COMPLETED` then `QTYSHIPPED` will contain a value and if the value is `1` the `QTYORDERED` will have a value.

What I need to do is within my query create one column which just has a `QTY` can someone show me how to achieve this in SQL Server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a simple `case` statement:

```
select (case when completed = 1 then QTYORDERED
             when completed = 3 then QTYSHIPPED
        end) as QTY
```

Note this will return NULL when `completed` has any other value.

You can also write this as:

```
select (case completed when 1 then QTYORDERED
                       when 3 then QTYSHIPPED
        end)
```

However, the first form is more general, giving you more flexibility for complicated logic.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
   CASE completed
      WHEN 1 THEN QTYORDERED 
      WHEN 3 THEN QTYSHIPPED
      ELSE 0  --Or add any logic when something goes wrong with "completed" value
   END as Quantity
FROM ....
```